# How can I manipulate files (delete, rename, create, etc) in pop-up file menu in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, nautilus

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04. While I must admit there are some amazing changes, there is one thing that really bugs me. Whenever I open the file menu through an action like attaching a file, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>, or something similar (not directly opening the file explorer), I cannot delete, create, rename, or manipulate files and directories in any way.

This is really annoying and I'm sure there must be a setting I can change to remove this functionality. Does anyone know it?

Comment: it looks like this might not be an available feature in all window managers. are you using unity window manager now? what if you select your old window manager when you are at the login screen? can you use the WM from 14.04?

Comment: Don't think there is. CTRL+o is for opening files only.

Comment: @JohnLexus Could you please add some links and/or screenshots with demonstration of *Rename* / *Delete* / *Create directory* from GtkFileChooser (standard file open and save dialog). I do not see any even in 14.04 LTS running default Unity. I see this functionality in MS Windows 7, but it is other story.

Comment: @mikewhatever It was available in ubuntu 14 :(

Comment: @N0rbert sorry I no longer have 14. That's weird, I guess I might have had a special WM, even though I have no memory of installing one.

Comment: @JohnLexus What was the name of WM on 14.04 LTS? GNOME, Xfce, Unity, LXDE, Cinnamon, KDE, MATE - what exactly?

Comment: @N0rbert I am pretty sure it was the standard - so, gnome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** seems to be not true, or half-true.

On both 14.04 LTS and 16.04 LTS user can *Create Folder* from the Save variant of GtkFileChooserDialog.

There are some differences in GtkFileChooserDialog functionality between Ubuntu versions.

On 14.04 LTS it has hardcoded (by `file_list_add_menu_item` and `file_list_add_check_menu_item` in `gtk+3.0-3.10.8/gtk/gtkfilechooserdefault.c`):

- *Visit File* in *Recent* items (opened by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>)
- *Copy Location* anywhere (in Open and Save)
- *Add to Bookmarks* for folders anywhere
- —
- checkbox *Show Hidden Files* anywhere
- checkbox *Show Size Column* anywhere

So there are no *Rename*, *Delete*, *Move to Trash* options.

---

On 16.04 LTS it has hardcoded (by `add_button` inside `file_list_build_popover` in [`gtk+3.0-3.18.9/gtk/gtkfilechooserwidget.c`](https://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/tree/gtk/gtkfilechooserwidget.c#n2257)):

- *Visit File* in *Recent* items (opened by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>)
- *Open With File Manager* for folders anywhere
- *Copy Location* anywhere
- *Add to Bookmarks* for folders anywhere
- *Rename* in Save dialog (**!**)
- *Delete* in Save dialog (**!**)
- *Move to Trash* in Save dialog (**!**)
- —
- checkbox *Show Hidden Files* anywhere
- checkbox *Show Size Column* anywhere
- checkbox *Show Time* anywhere
- checkbox *Sort Folders before Files* anywhere

---

**Notes:**
1. I can't find *Rename*, *Delete*, *Move to Trash*  functionality in GTK+2.0 version of GtkFileChooserDialog.
2. In GTK+2.0 the *New Folder*, *Delete File*, *Rename File* buttons are provided in deprecated GtkFileSelection (not sure about the name) [image: New Folder | Delete File | Rename File in GTK2] and it is rare use now. Screenshot above is for application from 2012 year.
3. Examples of GtkFileChooserDialog may be found in *Pickers* example from GTK+ packages with examples - `gtk2.0-examples` and `gtk-3-examples`.

Comment: What windows manager are you using? I'm just using the default one. I don't have those options on my WM

Comment: this only works with save (`ctrl+s`) and not open (`ctrl+o`)... weird right?